# Does 'invasion' imply the action is unjust?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Does 'invasion' imply the action is unjust? some people argue that the word 'invasion' implies the action is unpleasant, annoying and unwanted, as many dictionaries say, but not necessarily unjust. So, can we use invasion to describe a military action in another country that is righteous and judicious?

> VARIABLE NOUN
> If you refer to the arrival of a large number of people or things as an invasion, **you are emphasizing that they are unpleasant or difficult to deal with.**
>
> > ...this year's annual invasion of flies, wasps and ants.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/invasion)

Comment: The examples given are non-military ones involving insects or tourists. Military invasions might or not be described as right and just, although, as I am sure you will understand, a lot depends on who is doing the describing.

Comment: Just a note, since you are learning..  The 3rd person singular conjugation of the verb _to do_ is _does_, not _dose_.  "Does 'invasion' imply the action is unjust?"  The word _dose_ is most commonly used a noun, describing the size of a medication portion.

Comment: Just wanting to add an anecdotal piece of data: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution#Invasion Although the Glorious revolution in presented in some good light in Wikipedia (and I suppose modern British historiography does), the article uses "invasion" a lot of times.

Comment: First define "just", and then consider that Russia thinks that seizing Ukrainian territory is "just" because Russia denies that Ukraine's existence is valid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When applied to military forces, the word "invasion" is neutral.    The word itself doesn't imply something is good or bad.  You can use "invasion" for both the D-Day landings and the attacks on Ukraine.

On the other hand when used figuratively, it nearly always has a negative connotation.  "An invasion of insects" for example. If something is viewed as positive you don't use "invasion".  You don't say "the annual invasion of swallows" (as the arrival of these birds is seen as a good thing and a symbol of summer) - except by people who dislike the mess they create around their nests.

Comment: How do you apply unjust or just to an insect invasion?

Comment: Mostly true, but "The British Invasion" (60s music and counterculture) is an example of a positive use of the word (in a non-military sense)

Comment: Now we think of the British Invasion in a positive light. At the time, however, many people thought that this music was junk. I think it was the Beatles owning the top 10 for several months is what changed peoples' minds.

Comment: @Yorik There may also have been different sentiments towards the British Invasion depending on whether you were American or British.

Comment: @stackoverblown perspective.  Insects don't literally invade; we anthropomorphize it because we don't like it.

Comment: No, you cannot use "invasion" for the D-Day landings because, doh, they happened in France, which was an ally. The D-Day landings were reinforcement. Even if "invasion" is neutral in terms of whether it is just, it has to be some sort of trespass into enemy territory.  Enemy *occupied* territory doesn't really count.

Answer (score 14):

An invasion is the entry of Military forces of one country (or a group of countries acting together) into another, without invitation or authority from the country being invaded. Most often the purpose is to secure military control of the country invaded, or part of it.  A successful invasion often leads occupation or conquest of the country invaded, but not always.

Use of the word "invade" or "invasion" does not imply that the action is either "just" or "unjust". That is a judgement  call, and depends on the specific facts of the situation.

Comment: and regardless whether a particular military invasion is just, I'm sure you'll find that the object of the invasion finds it "unpleasant or difficult to deal with" :)

Comment: @Esther - ask the people of Belogorovka or Normandy and you might get a different perspective ...

Comment: @deep64blue : hey, just ask different people with different political views and belonging to different ethnic groups, within Belogorovka, and you might get different perspectives.

Comment: It's **perspective**, not "judgement".

Answer (score 2):

Initially it's all subjective:

- To the country that is invaded, it is obviously unjust.
- To the country that is invading, it is obviously just (or they wouldn't do it).

Over the long term, whether history records it as just or unjust is determined by the winner.

Comment: Not entirely correct - half of the activity during WWII involved "hostile invasions" of foreign territories. The other half involved "liberating invasions"...  The word on its own is essentially neutral when used about war.

Comment: At least relating to modern times, I disagree that it's all subjective, that opinion within the invading/invaded countries will run along state lines & that the "history is written by the victors" — for example, the invasion of Iraq in 2003 was declared illegal by the UN secretary general at the time; there was strong opposition/protests within the invading countries (e.g. US/UK) and history if anything records it as a bigger mistake than it was seen contemporarily

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers focus on technicalities or military- or military-historian-specific use of the word "invasion". That's fine, but being that this is ELL, I think it's important to note that to native English speakers (or at least to a lot), "invasion" has a negative connotation. As a native speaker, I was rather surprised to find others talking about D-Day as an "invasion", and if I heard that out of context, I would assume the speaker was a nazi apologist or at least someone trying to project an air of sophisticated superiority through "neutrality".

Yes, "invasion" implies that the act is unjust. This is why parties undertaking invasions go to the trouble of coming up with words to use in place of "invasion".

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Languages defines *invade* as *(of an armed force) enter (a country or region) so as to subjugate or occupy it*. Most people would regard doing that as 'unjust'. We all know that the Russian authorities regard their campaign in Ukraine as justified and therefore 'not an invasion'.

In response to Michael Harvey's comment - Some sources describe the D-Day Landings, intended to free countries already occupied by a foreign power, as an invasion.

Comment: So, was D-Day unjust?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Surely that wasn't intended to 'subjugate or occupy' but to free territories already occupied! (However, I see Wikipedia does describe it as an invasion.)

Comment: Interesting. Cambridge Dictionary uses D-Day as an example. On June 14, 1944 in Courseulles-sur-Mer he set up the provisional government of the French Republic, to prevent, it is said, the United States from setting up their own administration in France.  The subsequent entry into Germany, which was intended as (and resulted in) an 'occupation' is also called an 'invasion' by Wikipedia. Cambridge also gives a specifically US meaning "the act of entering a place by force, often in large numbers:"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm sure you are saying the same thing, but just to be clear - the D-Day landings, a perfectly just, and heroic, action on the part of Allied Forces, is frequently referrred to as an "invasion". I assume the "he" in your comment is de Gaulle. This would be more relevant to the History site, but the fact is that the Allied High Command, (following a demand from CdG) allowed Free French Forces to enter and liberate the city of Paris.  Bradley wanted his guys to do it but Eisenhower overruled him.

Comment: @WS2 - yes, indeed. Hasty editing on my part. I meant to say that de Gaulle knew of the 1942 agreement between Darlan and Mark Clark, that there would be an AMGOT in France, a _Vichy sans Vichy_ in fact, as well as (as happened), Italy, Germany & Austria. America realised that Vichy, like the Latin American regimes dear to its heart, was more malleable than a government with broad popular support.

Comment: @KateBunting Wikipedia and History.com are good examples of using Invasion morally vs. descriptively. Up front they call D-Day a "Landing" or "The Battle of Normandy". Only down below do they use "invasion" as a neutral description, having first established that morally it wasn't an invasion. Whereas the 1939 division of Poland is titled (in Wikipedia) "Invasion of Poland".

Comment: @OwenReynolds I'm not going to disagree with what you say here - the word may, among some writers, have acquired that sense. But the OED gives it an entirely descriptive meaning *The action of invading a country or territory as an enemy; an entrance or incursion with armed force; a hostile inroad.* Its examples (most recent 1856) also follow that pattern - for that is what invasions usually are. 1944 was to some extent exceptional in that sense. At least from an English-speaker's point of view.

Comment: But the french participated in D-Day landings! If that was an invasion, the french took part in the invasion of their own land and home? What?

Comment: @stackoverblown Descriptively that is what they did.

Comment: Staying on a WWII theme, the Allied activities in Sicily, the Italian mainland, and of Morocco are all commonly referred to as 'Invasions', and fairly equally referred to as "Liberations"...

Comment: @Stef  It was absolutely NOT an invasion of Vichy France. The latter, the part presided over by Petain - with German help - only existed in a defined region of South Eastern France, with its capital (I think) at Grenoble. The Allied Normandy invasion was conducted against Nazi Occupied France - and the opposing forces were not French but German.

Comment: @WS2 I'm fairly sure the capital or seat of government of Vichy France was the spa town, famous for its waters, of... Vichy

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ah yes, of course - "Vichy France'.  I had Grenoble in my mind, because I once read an account of someone who was at university there during the war with de Gaulle's nephew - also called de Gaulle. The latter won some sort of prize and when it was presented to him the whole assembly began chanting "Vive de Gaulle, Vive de Gaulle...". The Vichy police were doing their nuts, but numbers were such there was very little even they could do to stop them.

Comment: @WS2 - I love this story. I must say, it was interesting how the ordinary Vichy police accommodated the changes after the summer of 1944, and also at senior levels, especially Maurice Papon, who was personally awarded the Légion d'honneur by de Gaulle in 1961.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And what a bloody career that man had. When he ceased deporting French Jews for the Nazis, he began a campaign of torture and death in Algeria. Yet somehow he managed to end up in the cabinet of the urbane Valéry Giscard d'Estaing. The nature of twentieth century French history meant that a lot of politicians travelled a very long way in their lives.

Answer (score 1):

James K’s answer covers the important points, but one other important nuance is that an “invasion” is always an act of aggression (but see below).  So, if we call an attack an “invasion,” we’re implicitly saying that the invader is not the rightful owner of the territory and the attacker, not the defender, which might have implications for how justified it is.

So, the Institute for the Study of War is a pro-Ukraine source. [In its September 18 post](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-september-18), it refers to “the Russian invasion of Ukraine,” but “limited Ukrainian counterattacks,” “Ukrainian Counteroffensives,” and “Ukrainian efforts to liberate Russian-occupied territories” (which unmistakably expresses approval).

However, there is one exception: an amphibious attack is always an “invasion.”  In this one context, the word has no negative connotation.  For example, [the U.S. Navy itself describes its own naval landing at Inchon in June 1950 as “the Inchon invasion.”](https://www.history.navy.mil/browse-by-topic/wars-conflicts-and-operations/korean-war/korea-operations/inchon.html)  There are even references to the U.S. “invasion” of the Philippines in 1945, which was an American colony occupied by Japan at the time.

Comment: "*the invader is not the rightful owner*". Perhaps "current" or "de facto" would be more appropriate than "rightful". Was Germany the *rightful* owner of France in June 1944 when the Allies invaded?

Comment: @RayButterworth As I said, there’s one exception: an amphibious landing is always an “invasion.”

Comment: your definition seem a little fuzzy, how does water make it an invasion?

Comment: @Jasen That’s just how military historians use the word. An amphibious landing is a “naval invasion,” or just an “invasion.” In this one context, unlike other uses of the word, it has neutral connotations.